# Some other Exception in SDK or network happened: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I'm facing an issue with IDS V3 while trying to create Bill and TimeActivity. 
I get the message "Some other Exception in SDK or network happened: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset" but the big issue is sometime Object(Bill or TimeActivy) is properly created in my Quickbook company sometime not. my problem is that i can't how what's going on with the message Some other Exception in SDK or network happened: java.net.SocketException:". can someone help me? here is the logs:

```
2422 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG com.intuit.logger  - Request URI : https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/<myRealmID>/batch?requestid=c30972cb0e31488d912361196ef5bdbf&
2422 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG com.intuit.logger  - Http Method : POST
2422 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG com.intuit.logger  - Request Body : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<IntuitBatchRequest xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <BatchItemRequest bId="1" operation="create">
        <TimeActivity>
            <TxnDate>2014-02-18</TxnDate>
            <NameOf>Employee</NameOf>
            <EmployeeRef type="Employee">1543</EmployeeRef>
            <CustomerRef type="Customer">2477</CustomerRef>
            <ItemRef type="Item">4</ItemRef>
            <BillableStatus>Billable</BillableStatus>
            <HourlyRate>0</HourlyRate>
            <Hours>0</Hours>
            <Minutes>15</Minutes>
            <Description>Non Billable</Description>
        </TimeActivity>
    </BatchItemRequest>
</IntuitBatchRequest>

2592 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager  - Get connection for route {s}->https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com
2776 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator  - Connecting to quickbooks.api.intuit.com:443
3604 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  - CookieSpec selected: best-match
3614 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache  - Auth cache not set in the context
3614 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication  - Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
3614 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient  - Attempt 1 to execute request
3614 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection  - Sending request: POST /v3/company/<myRealmID>/batch?requestid=c30972cb0e31488d912361196ef5bdbf& HTTP/1.1
3615 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - >> "POST /v3/company/<myRealmID>/batch?requestid=c30972cb0e31488d912361196ef5bdbf& HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
3615 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - >> "content-type: application/xml[\r][\n]"
3615 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
3615 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - >> "Content-Encoding: gzip[\r][\n]"
3615 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - >> "Accept: application/xml[\r][\n]"
3616 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - >> "User-Agent: V3JavaSDK1.0.9[\r][\n]"
3616 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - >> "Authorization: OAuth oauth_token="qyprdeUmkyaDNaJIi6VsPRacpTKmC9NAwn9oCzUSjeCIMUz1", oauth_consumer_key="qyprdSSpOXpvrOIb0fMSqHMpM7wbtP", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1392753089", oauth_nonce="-4236080980365623833", oauth_signature="mR8fxPDbcYTdCYSuF%2BtEioBz3X4%3D"[\r][\n]"
3616 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - >> "Content-Length: 345[\r][\n]"
3616 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - >> "Host: quickbooks.api.intuit.com[\r][\n]"
3616 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
3616 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire  - >> "[\r][\n]"
3616 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers  - >> POST /v3/company/<myRealmID>/batch?requestid=c30972cb0e31488d912361196ef5bdbf& HTTP/1.1
3616 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers  - >> content-type: application/xml
3616 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers  - >> Accept-Encoding: gzip
3616 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers  - >> Content-Encoding: gzip
3616 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers  - >> Accept: application/xml
3616 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers  - >> User-Agent: V3JavaSDK1.0.9
3616 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers  - >> Authorization: OAuth oauth_token="qyprdeUmkyaDNaJIi6VsPRacpTKmC9NAwn9oCzUSjeCIMUz1", oauth_consumer_key="qyprdSSpOXpvrOIb0fMSqHMpM7wbtP", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1392753089", oauth_nonce="-4236080980365623833", oauth_signature="mR8fxPDbcYTdCYSuF%2BtEioBz3X4%3D"
3616 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers  - >> Content-Length: 345
3616 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers  - >> Host: quickbooks.api.intuit.com
3617 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers  - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
8433 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection  - Connection 0.0.0.0:53022<->206.108.41.19:443 closed
8433 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient  - Closing the connection.
8433 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection  - Connection 0.0.0.0:53022<->206.108.41.19:443 closed
8433 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG com.intuit.logger  - In retry request
8438 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection  - Connection 0.0.0.0:53022<->206.108.41.19:443 shut down
8439 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager  - Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl@599eb13a
8439 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-192.168.148.1] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager  - Connection can be kept alive for 9223372036854775807 MILLISECONDS
Some other Exception in SDK or network happened: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Answer (score 2):

The service is currently experiencing intermittent problems.  Our engineers are working on a fix.

http://developer-status.intuit.com/